drizzle ORM casting enum into text does not work using PostgresJS driver
I have a function like this where eg_status has enum type in postgres:
export async function fetchFilteredEvergreen(
    query: string,
    currentPage: number
) {
    noStore();

    const data = db.select({
        'Host': evergreen.hostname,
        'Environment': evergreen.environment,
        'IT Service': evergreen.it_service,
        'IT Service Owner': evergreen.service_owner,
        'Tech Version': evergreen.software_product_version_name,
        'Intended Remediation': evergreen.intended_remediation_date,
        'Evergreen Status': evergreen.eg_status,
        'Helios': evergreen.helios,
        'Instance': evergreen.instance_name,
        'GBGF': evergreen.it_org_6,
        'IT Org 7': evergreen.it_org_7,
        'IT Org 8': evergreen.it_org_8,
    })
    .from(evergreen)
    .where(or(
        sql<string>`cast(${evergreen.eg_status} as text) ilike ${sql.placeholder('search')}`,
        ilike(evergreen.eg_status,sql.placeholder('search')),
        ilike(evergreen.helios,sql.placeholder('search')),
        ))
    .limit(sql.placeholder('limit'))
    .prepare('evg_stmt')

    const res = await data.execute({search: `%${query}%`,limit: currentPage})

    console.log(res);

    return res
}

I though that sqlcast(${evergreen.eg_status} as text) ilike ${sql.placeholder('search')} would do the job and cast eg_statusinto text so i can useilike` but no, I get this error:
 ⨯ PostgresError: operator does not exist: egstatusenum ~~* unknown


I got rid of a similar issue by using the sql function like this.
sql<boolean>`invoices.amount::text ILIKE ${`%${query}%`}`

In your code it would look like this
sql<boolean>`evergreen.eg_status::text ilike ${sql.placeholder('search')}`

Hope that helps
